# What does the void statement in C do?

Tags: c, syntax, void

What does putting `void;` on a line do in C? The compiler is warning about it but i dont understand. What is the point in being able to put void on a line like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        void;
        printf("word dude");
        return 1;
}
```

eh

```
$ gcc -pedantic -ansi -Wall -Wextra eh.c -o eh
eh.c: In function 'main':
eh.c:4:2: warning: useless type name in empty declaration
$ ./eh
word dude
```

---

People seem to be getting confused what I'm asking: What does this line mean, does it do anything? why is it valid?

```
void;
```

---

Removed void cast as it's causing unnecessary discussion.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that what you've done is useless.  So what is the question here?

Comment: The real question is: why is that not a syntax error?

Comment: @Oil: the question is why this compiles, and what does it mean.

Comment: @megazord see my answer, this is not C. Your compiler is kind enough to accept it but it is not obligated to. `clang` for example refuses to translate this program.

Comment: It compiles because the compiler isn't enforcing strict conformance. It accepts empty declarations, though it warns about them. To get a compilation error, use `-pedantic-errors` or generally use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question got me interested because my first thought was K&R. I went back to my old K&R book (Appendix A p.192) on found blurb about declarations (transcripted):

```
8. Declarations

Declarations are used to specify the interpretation which C gives to each identifier; they do not necessarily reserve storage associated with the identifier. Declarations have
the form
    declaration:
        decl-specifier declarator-listopt;

The declarators in the declarator-list contain the identifiers being declared. The decl-specifiers consist of a sequence of type and storage class specifiers.
    decl-specifiers:
        type-specifier decl-specifiersopt
        sc-specifier decl-specifiersopt
```

This leads me to believe that delarator lists are optional (meaning it can be empty).

To add to this confusion on following page, it lists the set of legal *type-specifier* values and *void* is not one of them.

In my narrow interpretation that this may be still legal (but obsolete) C.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Comment: Well, IMO there is no clear answer.  For a long while, K&R _was_ the reference until ANSI C standardization. ANSI C is a superset of K&R, so a lot of the weirdness of K&R is inherited. Granted, it may not be complete, I think the best answer to "why does this valid" question is "because K&R said so."

Comment: i got here after googling in response to finding some odd lines in a github repo (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/96ad05c8e12bae3c53401d4a856c168ef6c04345/example/hello.c#L87) not entirely sure what repo is trying to acheive. maybe something to do with preventing compiler optimizing unused arguments away?

Answer (score 2):

```
      void;                       // 1
      (void)printf("word dude");  // 2
```

The first statement is an **invalid** statement: this is not C.

In the second statement the `(void)` cast makes your intent clear to discard the return value.  Another common use is to make silent some static analysis tools like Lint.

Answer (score 1):

```
void;
```

There's no point in doing that, it doesn't do anything.

Did you get this out of a book? Must be a mistake.

Somewhat unrelated, a return value if `0` is usually used to indicate the program terminated normally, any other value indicates a problem (by convention)

**Update**:

Looks like you added another line:

```
(void)printf("word dude");
```

this - unlike the previous `void;` - tells the compiler explictly to ignore the return value of the `printf()` function (the number of characters printed) and prevent warning messages a picky/pedantic setting on the compiler or other tools, like lint, to stop from complaining.

You don't see this for frequently used functions generally, though you may for others.

Comment: i know lol i typed 1 because iwas eating and it was easier to hit

Comment: @megazord ha ha .. best reason ever :).. and it doesn't really impact this example anyway.

Comment: @megazord I saw you added another line with `void printf(..)` .. I updated my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

It prints the same error if you change `void` with `int` or any other type.

`void` is a type and it expects something after that type. It has no sense at all as writing only `int` without a variable (or function) name after it.

Answer (score 0):

void is used as a data type in C, and come to think of it, I've never heard of an assembly language equivalent of NOP in C, so having void by itself on a line is probably an error.

Comment: im not asking what void is, Im asking what it means to just have a line by itself that says "void;"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the old style of declaring arguments to a function. That's equivalent to `int main(void)`. Some compilers still accept it, some don't. For example, this code compiles in two compilers I tried:

```
void main(i, j) {
    int;
    long;

    i = 12;
    j = 123456;
    printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
}
```

The answer to [Untyped arguments in a C function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692499/untyped-arguments-in-a-c-function-declaration) has a more precise definition for this case.

In any case, this is not recommended, so can we just stick with the "normal" way of declaring functions, please? :)

Comment: What you show isn't K&R style as I know it. In K&R style, the types are declared before the opening brace, along with their names. Here they're defined inside the function, without names. Is it yet-another definition style? Or maybe `i,j` are `int` by default, and `int;long;` are ignored?